# Perl Format dates

Tags: perl, date, posix, strftime

```
use Date::Calc qw(:all);
use Time::Piece;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
$a1 = '01.01.1963';
($year, $month, $day) = Decode_Date_US($a1);
print "$year $month $day\n";
$formatted = strftime('%m/%d/%Y',$month,$day,$year);
print "$formatted\n";
```

I am trying to format dates in a consistent format using POSIX(strftime). I am uncertain what the input format might be. I am using Decode_Date_US to extract the relevant year, month, day information. I am then trying to format the dates in consistent manner using strftime. I am getting following error 
**Usage: POSIX::strftime(fmt, sec, min, hour, mday, mon, year, wday = -1, yday = -1, isdst = -1) at test_dates.pl line 60**

Any help would appreciated. 
"use Time::Piece" would be eventually used to sort the dates.

Thanks

Comment: That format is not very _conistent_.  It's the same as the one you had before. Just with `/` instead of `.`.

Comment: @simbabque has made a good point. All you're doing is `s<\.></>g`!

Comment: This is just a test case. In the real case I wouldn't know beforehand what the format would be?
I am passing 3 arguments (month day year). What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you at least know the ordering of day/month/year? (and whether year is 2 digit or 4?) Because if you don't, you're stuck - 10/11/12 is inherently ambiguous, and there's no way to resolve that.

Comment: Re "*What am I missing here?*", As toolic pointer out, wrong number of arguments. They're also in the wrong order. Your usage: `strftime(fmt, mon, mday, year)` Actual usage: `strftime(fmt, sec, min, hour, mday, mon, year)`. Spend two seconds actually reading the error messages you get!!!

Answer (score 2):

Just use `Time::Piece` and `strptime`

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my $date = '01.01.1963';
my $timestamp = Time::Piece->strptime( $date, "%m.%d.%Y" );
print $timestamp -> strftime( "%m/%d/%Y")
```

But if the format is inconsistent, then you're onto a loser - for starters, there's plenty of places that transpose day/month ordering, or represent year as two digits (that sometimes will clash with month or day).

It's inherently ambiguous. You can - at best - apply some very crude guessing by grabbing groups of digits and *assuming* that they're in a consistent order.

E.g.

```
my ( $day, $month, $year ) = m/(\d{2}).*(\d{2}).*(\d{4})/; 

$timestamp = Time::Piece -> strptime ( "$year-$month-$day", "%Y-%m-%d" );
```

But you'll be tripped up by dates like `10/11/12` because you simply can't know which number is which field. You can try guessing, by `eval`ing the `strptime` and just retrying different formats until you get one that *does* decode to something valid.

As you indicate - Decode_Date_US basically does this so:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Date::Calc qw(:all);
use Time::Piece;
my $a1 = '01.01.1963';
my ($year, $month, $day) = Decode_Date_US($a1);
my $time = Time::Piece -> strptime("$year/$month/$day", "%Y/%m/%d");
print $time->strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),"\n";
```

Also - `use strict; use warnings;` is good.

And - there's *one* [correct way to write dates](https://xkcd.com/1179/). If you're going to reformat at all, then the one that isn't ambiguous is the best choice.

Comment: Decode_Date_US takes care of parsing any date format.
It is part of Date::Calc

Comment: In which case - parse it, feed it into a Time::Piece object, and use the inbuilt `strftime` rather than the posix one. (edited answer)

Comment: Running the above script crashes Perl command line interpreter.

Comment: @Bappa Nope. Must be something else you're doing.

Comment: Very strange. The above script keeps crashing for dates earlier than 1/1/1970.

Comment: Unix dates start in the first of January 1970.

Comment: @Bappa Define "crashing". This produces `1969-07-20` on my system: `perl -MTime::Piece -e 'print Time::Piece->strptime("1969/07/20", "%Y/%m/%d")->strftime("%Y-%m-%d")'`

Comment: I could reproduce on strawberry Perl / windows. Think there must be some bad handling of pre epoch.

Comment: I think it has to do with dates pre -1970. Doesn't "crash" for dates later than 1970.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using DateTime module's strftime function which can handle dates earlier than 1970. 
"Crashing" -Perl command line interpreter has stopped working. If it helps, I am using a windows machine and a very infrequent perl user.

this worked for me

```
use Date::Calc qw(:all);
use DateTime;
$dateformat = "%m/%d/%Y";
($year, $month, $day) = Decode_Date_US($date);
$date = DateTime->new(
                  year=>$year,
                  month=>$month,
                  day=>$day,            
        );
$date = $date->strftime($dateformat);
```

Comment: Pretty sure that's a Windows thing, rather than a Perl thing.